# Get values from observable other with subscribe() methode

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I have a function that retrieves values , inside it I use observable.

```
this.values$ = this.apiService.retrieveIndicatorHistory(this.indicatorName, this.currentPeriod)
  .pipe(
    tap(_res => console.log(`value: ${_res}`)),
    map(
      (_res: any) => {
      this.indicatorService.changeLoadingIndicator(this.indicatorName, false);
        return _res;
      }
    ),
    catchError((err: any) => {
      this.indicatorService.changeLoadingIndicator(this.indicatorName, false);
      return of(err);
    })
```

In the same file I have a function that needs the values returned by the observable.

```
 this.valuesCopy = _.cloneDeep(this.values$);
```

I get this error

`error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.`

I know that I should subscribe to the observable an retrieve values (inside `retrieveIndicatorHistory` function)

I would to know if is there  `this.values$ | async` aquivalent in TS files?

Comment: We don't have any async equivalent in TS File. You need to use subscribe inorder to read observable values and apply deepClone on it.

Comment: You could just use promises instead. The `async` pipe will still work and you can `await` the result in js. `obs$.pipe(toPromise())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share complete file and package.json.
This is clearly a TYPE issue. You can only assign value of similar type in Typescript.

But Answer to this question can be found here.
[Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type '[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819805/type-observableany-is-not-assignable-to-type)